# Нет полосы прокрутки в scrollview

Tags: android, android-scrollview

Проблема в том что полосы прокрутки нет. А вроде должна быть.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/scrollView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
  android:fillViewport="true"
  android:isScrollContainer="true"
  android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/daily_fragment_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/backgroundActivityColor"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

-----------тут вьюшки разные

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image: снизу еще должна быть textview]

Вот так выглядит на 10 дюймах

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: android:scrollbars="vertical" ?

Comment: @pavlofff пробовал. не помогает.

Comment: решил. вдруг кому-то поможет: сделал у листвью  android:layout_height="match_parent". + нижний элемент привязал к нижнему краю ConstraintLayout.

Comment: @EvgenyGooDi, напишите это в ответ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил. вдруг кому-то поможет: сделал у `ListView` `android:layout_height="match_parent"` + нижний элемент (у меня это `TextView`) привязал к нижнему краю `ConstraintLayout`